# Web part personalization permissions on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, personalization

What are the minimum SharePoint 2010 permissions required to allow a user to personalize a web part page, allowing updates and adding web parts to the page but completely restrict the user modifying the shared version?

I initially copied the built-in “Read” permission level and added the “Manage Personal Views”, “Add/Remove Personal Web Parts” and “Update Personal Web Parts” permissions from the Personal Permissions group. This custom permission level was then applied to a user who then viewed a web part page created by the Administrator, which contained only a very simple prototype SharePoint web part. This web part contained a modifiable label which was edited using the “Miscellaneous” section from the Edit Web Part from the standard SharePoint chrome.

With the custom permission level applied the “Miscellaneous” option it is not available to the user upon personalizing the page and selecting Edit Web Part. The “Miscellaneous” option only becomes available to the user when the permission level is further modified to have the “Edit Items” from the List Permissions group. This has the undesired effect of allowing the user to be able to modify the shared version of the page.

Is what I’m trying to achieve even possible?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://akifkamalsyed.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/personalizable-web-part-custom-property-not-shown-for-users-with-contribute-permission-level/

It's probably because you don't have a safecontrol for the webpart with the attribute SafeAgainstScript